# Exclude MSTest tests from specific classes in TeamCity steps

Tags: teamcity, mstest, vstest, vstest.console.exe

Because you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15810215/419956) set a Test Category on a Test Class with MSTest, I've opted to do something similar in the name, postfixing test classes with `...IntegrationTests` whenever they contain slow running tests.

In the Visual Studio Test Explorer I can exclude these tests by using:

```
-class:IntegrationTests
```

However, in TeamCity, this option doesn't work. I'm using the VSTest 2017 test engine version in the latest version of TeamCity. However, it seems it only has a `TestCaseFilter` option that seems to be missing the option to exclude tests in a certain class?

I used [this VSTest.ConsoleRunner documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) and [this post about the `TestCaseFilter`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vikramagrawal/2012/07/23/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-rc-using-testcasefilter/) to reach that conclusion. I've also read through the [runsettings file documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx) to see if it contains any info, but no luck.

My goal is to have 1 TeamCity step that runs all tests in classes that are *not* "marked" as being slow, and another followup step with the tests in classes that *are* marked.

The only workaround I currently see would be to split *all* of my test projects into two projects, and move those integration test classes to separate assemblies. I'd rather not do that.

Bottom line: **how to exclude tests in classes where the class name contains a specific string?**

Answer (score 1):

TestCategory attribute can be used at the class/assembly level. See here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2017/02/25/mstest-v2-now-and-ahead/.

Also, please see same twitter thread here: https://twitter.com/pvlakshm/status/844905609409564672